# Search and replace serialized object in phpMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, csv, import

I need to erase a specific meta value for a specific meta key. The table is `post_meta`. The meta key is `awards`. And the meta_value I want to search and replace (erase) is:

```
a:1:{i:0;s:0:"";}
```

This value should be blank, instead of containing that empty serialized array.

I tried to use this query:

```
update wp_postmeta 
   set meta_value = replace(meta_value,'a:1:{i:0;s:0:"";}','')
 where meta_key = 'awards'
```

But I get this error:

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''a:1:{i:0)' at line 1

I assume the error is because the text I'm searching for includes quotation marks and symbols. How can I formulate the query properly?

Thank you!

EDIT to add context if needed: I imported 10,000 posts to the database using a CSV. All worked fine except this object/array `a:1:{i:0;s:0:"";}` was imported as the meta_value when no value existed for this particular meta_key. I need this value to be empty, so now I want to erase this value from the database wherever it appears.

Comment: *" How can I formulate the query properly?"* Not a update anyway `select id, meta_value from meta_key  where = 'awards' `   use a loop use PHP unserialize check the value change the value if it matches then update that total serialize value to the table..

Comment: I have a feeling your escaping isn't working as you expect.

Comment: @tadman Hiya. I noticed the edit you made earlier. It looks like you had an issue with the `#` symbol. The trick is to indent and escape it. ;-) I re-edited.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner Thanks. The `#` was making it pretty angry and huge-bold.

Comment: How are you running this query? This should be fine, but it really depends on how you're executing it, and that should be through WPDB.

Comment: @tadman Welcome. Yeah, I remember the first times I saw what you said and I figured it out for myself, when I thought of doing the same thing in comments for certain characters that don't show up well. Oh well... "sharing the wealth" as it were ;-)

Comment: @tadman, I'm running it in the SQL tab of phpMyAdmin. The error comes when I click the "simulate query" button.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner I'm not using wordpress syntax... at least I don't think I am? I'm just trying to run a search and replace on the database. The value I need to replace is `a:1:{i:0;s:0:"";}`

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner Sorry, the database is for a wordpress site. I guess I was being overzealous in my tagging. I will try to remove.

Comment: Ok thanks. I just added the "phpmyadmin" tag since there is relevance. What is that type of data? Is that JSON?

Comment: I believe it is a php serialized object (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27205345/what-kind-of-data-format-is-that). I just want to remove that phrase.

Comment: Your query is just fine.  Actually run it instead of doing the "Simulate Query" and it should work.

Comment: @PatrickQ so there is a dupe for this after all(?)

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner  From my reading of that, yeah.

Comment: @PatrickQ Looks good from my end. I used the dupe you flagged as, cheers. I almost voted as unclear earlier.

Comment: Oh geez! I didn't consider the issue was just with the simulate query button. I thought I was being responsible by testing it before running.

Comment: Apparently the query tester isn't as smart as it thinks it is and is getting confused by perfectly valid syntax.

Comment: Yep, the real thing worked just fine. Sorry for wasting everyone's time. Should I delete the question?

Answer (score 0):

The error indicates that escape `;`. Like:

```
set meta_value = replace(meta_value,'a:1:{i:0\;s:0:\"\"\;}','')
```

Comment: Thank you. I still get the same error with this code as well.

Comment: `;` isn't a magical character inside of strings.

Comment: @tadman can you explain what you mean? The meta_value is `a:1:{i:0;s:0:"";}` and I need to erase that whole thing.

Comment: What I mean is this shouldn't be an issue, and shouldn't require escaping.